# rtcmulticonnection: webrtc recordrtc not returning a blob

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to simply record the webrtc video using what I though was a standard example. The library is here: https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection

```
rtcMultiConnection.onstream = function(e) {
  var mediaElement = getMediaElement(e.mediaElement, {
        onRecordingStarted: function(type) {
            // www.RTCMultiConnection.org/docs/startRecording/
            rtcMultiConnection.streams[e.streamid].startRecording();
        },
        onRecordingStopped: function(type) {
            // www.RTCMultiConnection.org/docs/stopRecording/
            rtcMultiConnection.streams[e.streamid].stopRecording(function(blob){
              console.log("test");
              console.log(blob);
            });
        }});}
```

I can follow the steps through the function calls, the issue is that the callback is never run from recordrtc.js....

It goes to line 100 of https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/blob/master/RecordRTC.js

There it runs:

```
mediaRecorder.stop(_callback);
```

Which never calls the callback....

Even calling functions directly doesn't work:

```
        console.log(rtcMultiConnection.streams[e.streamid].audioRecorder.getBlob());
        console.log(rtcMultiConnection.streams[e.streamid].videoRecorder.save("a.png"));
```

I am wondering if two different versions of recordrtc and rtcmulticonneciton are interacting.... Any ideas? Maybe an older recordrtc, but I can't find an older version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use [`blob.video`](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/v2.2.2/demos/RecordRTC-and-RTCMultiConnection.html#L184-L198):

```
var stream = connection.streams['stream-id'];
stream.stopRecording(function(blob) {
    var h2;
    if (blob.audio) {
        h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.innerHTML = '<a href="' + URL.createObjectURL(blob.audio) + '" target="_blank">Open recorded ' + blob.audio.type + '</a>';
        div.appendChild(h2);
    }
    if (blob.video) {
        h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.innerHTML = '<a href="' + URL.createObjectURL(blob.video) + '" target="_blank">Open recorded ' + blob.video.type + '</a>';
        div.appendChild(h2);
    }
});
```

---

#### Updated at March 29, 2016

Here is the actual documentation:

- http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/startRecording/

Please make sure that:

1. You are using v2.2.2
2. You called `startRecording` first

For v3, you can directly use the RecordRTC:

```
connection.onstream = function(event) {
    recordStream(event.stream);
};

function recordStream(stream) {
    if (!!window.recorder) return;
    window.recorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
        type: 'video'
    });
    recorder.startRecording();
}

btnStopRecording.onclick = function() {
    if (!window.recorder) return;
    recorder.stopRecording(function() {
        var blob = recorder.blob;

        // or dataURL
        recorder.getDataURL(func_callback);
    });
};

btnStartRecording.onclick = function() {
    var stream = connection.attachStreams[0];
    recordStream(straem);

    // or
    var stream = connection.streamEvents['stream-id'].stream;
    recordStream(straem);
};
```

Above snippet can be used within v2.2.2 as well.

Comment: sadly, the function isn't called at all, blob.video or not... no log is written

Comment: The new version of using RecordRTC is now working. You might want to check some of the documented code, because my code above did work once upon a time. I am guessing the stream expected has changed or something in recordrtc. Either way, it works now. Thanks!